# UCDetector to identify unused parameters

Tags: java, parameters

I'm looking to remove the unused param "unusedInt" int the following code:

```
    public class Class1 {

    final int anInt1 = 33;
    final int anInt2 = 44;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class1();
    }

    public Class1() {
        doSomething(anInt1, anInt2, -1111);
    }

    public void doSomething(int a, int b, int unusedInt) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) if (i == 32) System.out.println(a);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < b; ii++) if (ii == 43) System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

The doSomething() method utilizes params "a" and "b" but ignores "unusedInt". Can UCDetector detect these unused parameters? If not is there an eclipse extension that can?

Comment: Why not just overload **doSomething()** so that you have another method that doesn't contain the **unusedInt** parameter. This would be allowed since the two methods would have different signatures. OR make the **unusedInt** parameter optional?

Comment: I have hundreds of classes with methods containing unused parameters. They pass a useless int or long. I've got the "warning" turned on for them to quickly identify and edit the method signature.